# How does one have a time triggered script retry when there is a server error?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a script that runs every morning (between 5am and 6am):

```
for (nn=1;nn<datacommit.length;++nn){ 

if (+datacommit[nn][7]==owneremail ) {

if (+datacommit[nn][4]==+datacommit[nn][8] ) { 
   MailApp.sendEmail(datacommit[nn][7], "30 day Commitment Reminder for"+" "+agname,
                     datacommit[nn][2]+","+ " \n " +"It is 30 days before You promised "+ agname + ":"+ " \n"
                     + datacommit[nn][0]+ " \n"
                     + "Please check in with "+" "+ datacommit[nn][3]+ "." + " \n" + htmlBody + ": " + url, {noReply:true})} else {};}
```

as a reminder for myself.  (The script works just fine. I didn't include all the vars... just wanted to show what the script does.)   However, sometimes I get an email saying that it did work due to a "server error" and to wait and try again.  So, when I get that email, I assume the script does NOT automatically try again (well until the NEXT morning).  So, is there a way to automatically have it run again if there is a server error?  Maybe with the logger?  if the logger captures server errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your code into a `Try, Catch` error handling statement, and if there is an error, put the code in the `catch` block to sleep with `Utilities.sleep()`.  The code will resume running on the next line after the line of code with the sleep timeout.

[Google Documentation - Utilities Sleep](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#sleep(Integer))

```
function testTimeout() {
  try {
    var timeIs = new Date();
    Logger.log('Time is: ' + timeIs);
    var makeAnError = functionCallToNowwhere();
  } catch(err) {
    Utilities.sleep(3000);
    var timeIs = new Date();
    Logger.log("Back to Life Now!! " + timeIs);
  }
};
```